# Knockout loses bindings when Google Maps API v3 info window is closed

Tags: google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I'm data binding to a div which I am then setting as the content of an InfoWindow. When markers on the map are clicked I'm changing the bound observable, which updates the content in the info window. All of this works fine until the info window is closed. Google Maps removes the info window from the DOM, along with my div which had the bindings on it. Re-opening the info window results in its contents being frozen in the state it was in at its closing.

Any changes to the observable no longer update the ui, including using valueHasMutated. I've tried just resetting the content of the info window and rebinding, but the JQuery element still exists and I get duplicated content. I've also tried using cleanNode and rebinding but also get duplicate content with that.

The div which I'm binding too:

```
<div id="placeTmpl" data-bind="with: place">
        <h3>
            <a data-bind="text: name, attr: { 'href': detailsUrl($data) }"></a>
        </h3>
</div>
```

The Google Maps InfoWindow:

```
window.infoWindow = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ''
});
window.infoWindow.setContent($('#placeTmpl')[0]);
```

Event listener and updating observable

```
window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    window.viewModel.openInfoWindow(marker, data);
});

self.openInfoWindow = function (marker, data) {
   for (var i = 0; i < self.places().length; i++) {
        if (self.places()[i].placeId == data.PlaceId) {
            self.place(self.places()[i]);
        }
    }
    window.infoWindow.open(map, marker);
};
```

Like I said, this all works great until the info window is closed. I'm just looking for a way to force knockout to start updating the ui again or to clear and rebind when the info window is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to go around this by setting the InfoWindow content as an html string rather than a DOM node.

i.e:

```
window.infoWindow.setContent($('#placeTmpl').html());
```

rather than:

```
window.infoWindow.setContent($('#placeTmpl')[0]);
```

By doing this the html with the knockout bindings remains in place, rather than being transferred into the info window where it was subsequently being destroyed on close. Knockout now updates the bounded DOM elements as usual and I just update the info window with the html string on each click.

If you try to put knockout bindings in a Google Maps InfoWindow, you're gonna' have a bad time.

Comment: thanks
I had exactly the same problem
I wasted few hours struggling around without success, until I found your answer

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this without having to resort to using strings when calling `setContent`. In my case, the info window had dynamic elements that would update while the info window was open, so the string solution would not have taken this into account.

I added a `closeclick` handler in which I keep track of the original DOM element I passed to the info window and just add the element back to the body after the info window took it out. This keeps knockout happy and the info window doesn't care.

```
var $node = $('#placeTmpl');

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: $node[0]
});

google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, "closeclick", function () {
    //google maps will destroy this node and knockout will stop updating it
    //add it back to the body so knockout will take care of it
    $("body").append($node);
});
```

Comment: Nice solution - good to keep the binding goodness. Better than the hack chosen as answer IMO